# Is it possible to add a colored frame/border to the screen as an Android service so, users can navigate through apps while the frame is there?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

I want to add a colored frame on the screen as a service so the user can use other apps while the frame is there. Is this possible? For example, the red frame on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xitjW.jpg).

Comment: unless you tell us what exactly you have in mind,we will never be able to respond!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I just want to make a simple mock-up tool—a privacy nudge—that communicates to the user camera access by any application by showing a colored border/frame on the screen. The user should be able to use other apps while the border is there. Is it possible to have a frame as an android service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, It is possible. I managed to build such a tool.

I created a FloatingWindow class which extends [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service). Within the FloatingWindow, I created a [WindowManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager) and set it to be full screen.

I set the [WindowManager.LayoutParameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams) to be *FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE* | *FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE*.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(width, height, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

I set the parent layout to be RelativeLayout and transparent. Then I added 4 Children (4 RelativeLayouts filled with the same color: 2 for the columns and 2 for the rows). [Here's a screenshot of the tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj8Zl.png).